# use jqgrid on dynamically loaded html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I have a modal dialog which loads its body via AJAX call. In loaded body I have HTML markup to use `jqGrid`.

```
$.get('@Url.Action("ListPartial")',null, function(data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
                 customModal('Modal header', data);
                 createListGrig("");
              });
```

The `customModal` method

```
function customModal(title, body) {
    var modal = $('#modalDialog');
    modal.find('h6.modal-title').html(title);
    modal.find('#modalBody').html(body);
    modal.modal();
}
```

And `createListGrig` method applies `jqGrid` on loaded html.

The problem is that when my modal appears the grid has 0 width. But when I'm adding setTimeout for 1 second it appears as expected.

```
setTimeout(function (){createListGrig("")}, 1000);
```

Please help me figure out exact moment to apply `jqGrid`

Comment: What is `modal()` method? I guess this plugin should have a `load/shown` event if it is working async in some way (using animation?). BTW, what is doing `createListGrig()` method?

Comment: Thank you @A.Wolff ! You point me on the right way I just called `createListGrig("")` method in `shown` callback and it starts work as expected. BTW: `modal()` - twitter bootstrap modal. `createListGrig()` calls somthing like this `$("#list-grid").jqGrid({})` with my parameters.

Comment: Please feel free to add it as answer so this question could be marked as solved  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @A.Wolff mentioned in his comment the correct moment is when `shown` method of modal is called.
I updated my code like this to make it work correctly:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("ListPartial")',null, function(data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
                customModal('Copy Address from Partner', data, function() {
                    createListGrig("");
                });
            });
```

And `customModal` method

```
function customModal(title, body, callBack) {
    var modal = $('#modalDialog');
    modal.find('h6.modal-title').html(title);
    modal.find('#modalBody').html(body);
    modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if (callBack) callBack();
    });
    modal.modal();
}
```